# Laravel - How to maintain a object in different controllers?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to the Laravel framework, and hopefully, someone can save my life!

So I am making a WEB application demo by using Laravel, and I use Vus as the front-end. I send the request from Vue to Laravel's controller, but I am wondering if I can maintain the object inside the controller when I finish one HTTP request, then I can still use the object's property data in another request (the request could be in the same controller or another controller)?

Especially the object I want to maintain has some properties like token and expired time, and a function inside to check if the token is expired or not. So I would like to keep these properties inside the object and just store them in the memory.

```
class OneController extends Controller
{
    private object $object;
    public function __consturct()
    {
       // Do something to $this->object
    }
}
```

```
class AnotherController extends Controller
{
    private object $object;
    public function __consturct()
    {
       // Do something to $this->object
    }
}
```

I don't know if I describe my problem clearly, so don't hesitate to tell me if you want more context!

Thank you, World!

Comment: This is one of the purposes of your database. You store the state of the object to be used everywhere.

Comment: @Savlon Heyy :) Thank you for your reply! But the object I want to maintain has some properties like token and expired time, and a function inside to check if the token is expired or not. So I would like to keep these properties inside the object and just store them in the memory.

Comment: Store it in a cookie

Comment: Why not use [Laravel's Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum) - authentication system for SPA?